# AutoFill and retrieve data from other pages in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, curl, phantomjs

I have a problem in PHP, following requests:

- Run my php file, it moved to the "https://whoer.net/checkwhois"
- It will automatically fill in the "IP address or hostname" is the text "8.8.8.8" and it automatically press the "Check"
- Save the entire results Check

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this CURL from linux shell

```
curl 'https://whoer.net/checkwhois' -H 'origin: https://whoer.net' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'referer: https://whoer.net/checkwhois' -H 'authority: whoer.net' --data 'partial=1&host=8.8.8.8' --compressed
```

In php the below code should work:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://whoer.net/checkwhois');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  'partial=1&host=8.8.8.8');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: You are great, thank you very much. I need to learn CURL! Thanks for helping me realize my problem